# Individual Input Validation on Blur

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to use HTML5 to validate a number input. I am using jQuery to create the element. How can I have the browser display the error message onBlur without having to click the submit button?

`jQuery(document.createElement('input')).attr({"type":"number","min":"0","max":"60","step":"1","value":"5"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't invoke the native validation ui through an API. Due to the fact, that the the validation ui automatically also focuses the element, this would not be a good usability (user can't leave field invalid and decide to do something else on the page).

If you want to do this: you have to implement the validation yourslf using the validity property and the validationMessage property. The code could look like this:

```
$('input[type="number"]').blur(function(){
    //if field is validation candidate and is invalid alert the validationmessage
    if( $.prop( this, 'willValidate' ) && !$.prop( this, 'validity').valid){
        alert( $.prop( this, 'validationMessage' );
    }
});
```

Of course using an alert, is a little bit stupid, but makes the code clean. If you want to use webshims lib, there is a showError helper. I have put up a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/DTqxA/)

About the helper method $.webshims.validityAlert.showFor:

showFor requires a dom element jQuery object or selector as first argument.
the validationmessage as optional second
and the last is a boolean, which will show the message without focusing the field.

Comment: Ah thanks! This is a really nice replacement for the native UI validation. Although would be really nice if they implemented individual validation.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a .blur() handler.  See [here](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document.createElement('input')).attr({"type":"number","min":"0","max":"60","step":"1","value":"5"}).blur(function(){
    var val = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(),10);
    if(val < parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('min'), 10))
        jQuery(this).val(parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('min'), 10)); // Set value to min
    if(val > parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('max'), 10)){
       jQuery(this).val(parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('min'), 10)); // Set value to max
});
```

Something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

Below code solved my problem

```js
 $("input[type=number]").blur(function(){                             
     if(parseInt($(this).val())>parseInt($(this).attr("max"))){
           $(this).val($(this).attr("max"));
     }else if(parseInt($(this).val())<parseInt($(this).attr("min"))){
        $(this).val($(this).attr("min"));
     }
});
```